# Drupal: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, drupal

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in invTranslate_translated_menu_link_alter() (line 55 from \sites\all\modules\custom\invTranslate\invTranslate.module).

invTranslate.module is a custom module.

```
function invTranslate_translated_menu_link_alter(&$item) {
  static $nodeMenu;
  if ($nodeMenu === NULL) {
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && count(arg() == 3 && (arg(1) == 'add' || arg(2) == 'edit'))) {
      $nodeMenu = true;
      ...
```

Line 55 is:
`if (arg(0) == 'node' && count(arg() == 3 && (arg(1) == 'add' || arg(2) == 'edit'))) {`.
Please help.

Comment: `arg() == 3 && (arg(1) == 'add' || arg(2) == 'edit')` is a logical expression, that will result in either true or false. Using count on true or false simply makes zero sense.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can change that code to right code?

Comment: @04FS just deleting "count"? so the result would be `if (arg(0) == 'node' && (arg() == 3 && (arg(1) == 'add' || arg(2) == 'edit'))) {`

Comment: That would be the most likely guess, yes. (Guess, because we have not been told what this is supposed to achieve in the first place.)

Comment: Depending on what `arg()` returns it could be `count(arg()) == 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems there is a simple typo, however it depends on what your code should do. I've split the code to multiple rows for better readability:

```
if (
    arg(0) == 'node'
    && count(arg() == 3   //the count method takes as param the bool from the row below too
    && (arg(1) == 'add' || arg(2) == 'edit'))
) {
```

Instead it should look like this:

```
 if (
    arg(0) == 'node'
    && count(arg()) == 3   // add right bracket after arg()
    && (arg(1) == 'add' || arg(2) == 'edit')   // remove right bracket from here
) {
```

Comment: @sailormoon Please consider voting this answer as a final (green mark on the left), if it helped you resolve the case. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for help, final answer is yours.

Answer (score 1):

> arg() Returns a component of the current Drupal path.
>   When viewing a page at the path "admin/structure/types", for example, arg(0) returns "admin", arg(1) returns "structure", and arg(2) returns "types".
>   https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7.x

In durpal the paths for nodes are like these

- /node/add/{node-type}/
- /node/{nid}/edit
- /node/{nid}

Looking back at the code:
`if (arg(0) == 'node' && count(arg() == 3 && (arg(1) == 'add' || arg(2) == 'edit')))`

I think, that condition should only pass for the first 2 of the paths I mentioned. So changing the code to the following should result in the expected behaviour:
`if (arg(0) == 'node' && count(arg()) == 3 && (arg(1) == 'add' || arg(2) == 'edit'))`

The count() should only check if we have enough components in the path.